# With respect to

Tags: word-usage

Is the Use of with respect to correct in these sentences -

LG phones are better with respect to the Samsung ones.

Nepal is preferred over any other south asian country by tourists all over the world because it provides way more things with respect to the price that they offer it for.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of your sentences is idiomatic.

Your first sentence comparing two brands of phones should read:

> LG phones are better than Samsung ones.

However, if you were comparing different features of those phones, you might write:

> With respect to camera quality, LG phones are better than Samsung ones.

Synonyms for *with respect to* are:

> with reference to, in relation to, apropos of, with regard to

So they generally refer to a particular aspect of something, or are used to digress from the theme previously being discussed.

Your second sentence should read:

> Nepal is preferred ......because it offers better value for money.

**Way more things** is slang, and

**Way more things with respect to the price that they offer for it** is both clumsy and unclear.

However, you might write:

> With respect to price (value for money), Nepal is preferred to any other south Asian country.....